# Alert rules on specific times

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is it possible to trigger an alert every day at 00:00? I want to send a daily report at that time. I does not look like it in the UI but want to be sure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this UI does not support this feature `alert at 00:00 per day`. The settings in your post "Period as 1440, and Frequency as 1440" only makes sure alert once per 24 hours, but the triggered time cannot be specified.

As a workaround, you can use azure web job(timer trigger) or azure function(timer trigger) with [application insights rest api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart). But you should write a lot of code for that.